# How to keep running when hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Continuously I want to create a function that runs a few seconds after I hover my mouse, like 'update' function.

But I did not find a way to run continuously when hovering.

Please let me know if you know how to do it.

Comment: use `.mouseenter()`

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to run something a few seconds later.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information / a concrete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery makes me want to puke, so, yeah.. native JS;

(Click the blue "run code snippet" button at the bottom of the post and hover the "hover me" button)

```js
var hover;
btn.addEventListener('pointerover', function(evt){
  // We have started hovering the btn, start interval.
    hover = setInterval(function(){
      //every 1000 MS, add another "Hi" to the debug div.
      debug.innerHTML += "Hi  ";
    }, 1000);
    
});

btn.addEventListener('pointerout', function(evt){
  //Leaving & stopped hovering the btn, stop interval.
  clearInterval( hover );
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Hover Me</button>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to trigger a behavior a few seconds after an event has occurred.  You can do this in jquery with the [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function, e.g.

```
$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

To combine this with mouseenter it'd be something like

```
$( "#foo" ).mouseenter(function(){
   $( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
});
```